# How do I resize the display size of woocommerce products?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce and wordpress for a small online shop. To display the products I use the woocommerce shortcode like this.

```
[products category="Keys" limit="2"]
```

The problem is that the result being displayed on the screen is too large.

How do I resize it? Do I need to add my own CSS or are there shortcode flags where I can add height and width parameters? In the attached screenshot you can see the displayed image is too wide and very long.

HOw do I resize the section that is displayed using the shortcode?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#display-product-attributes) you can find the complete list for the attributes of the WooCommerce `[products]` shortcode.

You can set the **columns** attribute by increasing the number of columns to 4 or 5 (or more) so that you have the smallest product block:

```
[products category="Keys" limit="2" columns="5"]
```

If that's not enough, you'll need to add CSS rules.

Comment: Thank you, since it does not look like there is a way to resize using the shortcodes I will use CSS.